# Power and speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I'm asked to calculate how much POWER a 1210kg car needs to drive with a 85 km/s speed up a 655 meter long slope of 4.5°. I can find how much energy and work is required to do this, but isn't POWER=WORK over TIME? I don't have any time in my problem.

So I ask: If I have a 1000kg car and I drive 500 meters...Could I go 100 km/h with even 1 horse power as long as I got enough time? Is horse power only an indicator of torque (i.e. work over time)?

Comment: You don't actually need to know the length of the slope to answer this. You multiply by the length to get the total work, but then you divide by (length/speed) so length cancels out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any time in Your problem, but You can easily calculate it - it is the time it would take to drive 655 meters with 85km/h (I guess that 85km/s in Your question is a mistake), so simply $t=s/v$. If You already calculated the amount of work, simply multiply it by the time calculated, and You'll have the solution.

Comment: In the next question, I am asked: We assume that the same force of friction affects the car at all times during regular driving. How much does the car spend in gas per 100km if the heat displacement of gas is 38 mj per liter and the engine's efficiency is 21%?

(the force of friction was calculated to be 653N before).

Now how do I read this? What is ''normal driving''? This question is insanely ambiguous to me...

Comment: The total work of friction is then 653*100000=6.53*10^7 I guess..?

Comment: The work done against the friction force is $6.53*10^7$ Joules, which is $65.3$ Mega Joules. Divide it by $38$ MJ/liter and You know how much gas the engine would spend if it had 100% efficiency. Divide it by 0.21 and You have the actual gas consumption.

Comment: ah I thought it may be like that, but I was not at all sure. Thanks a lot again.